# test html5 mode in jwplayer

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I am working with JWPlayer 6 using a Flash enabled browser.

How can I get JWPlayer 6 to use HTML 5 even if flash is installed.

I currently have the following config for JWPlayer:

```
jwplayer("player").setup({
    type: 'rtmp',
    streamer: "<?php echo "$wowza/$app_name"; ?>",
    height: 540,
    width: 960,
    'autostart': 'true',
    'bufferlength': '3',
    'file': '<?php echo $stream_name; ?>'
});
```

lee

Answer (score 3):

JWPlayer will opt to use the HTML5 version over a Flash version with any capable browser.
http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28837/browser-device-support#modes

You will need to list both the RTMP stream AND the HLS url within your sources in order for the JW Player to fall back.
http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29394/hls-with-mp4-fallback

This is what that might look like for you:

```
jwplayer("player").setup({
    type: 'rtmp',
     sources: [{
          file: "<?php echo "$wowza/$app_name"; ?>"
        },{
          file: "<?php echo "$wowza/$app_name"; ?>/playlist.m3u8"
        },{
          file: "http://non-wowza/assets/myVideo.mp4"
        }],
    height: 540,
    width: 960,
    'autostart': 'true',
    'bufferlength': '3',
    'file': '<?php echo $stream_name; ?>'
});
```

Comment: That's not true. You can configure JWPlayer to prefer either HTML5 or Flash and use the other option as fallback.

Comment: What exactly "isn't true"? If his browser supported it then it would play in HTML5 according to JWPlayer documentation. He clearly needs to adjust something in his video/streamer or he doesn't have a modern browser.

Comment: Thanks Brent for the links. I actually read the one that mentions that, but I guess it didn't register. Well, I tried to load JWPlayer using Chrome 26 which, from what I can tell from the HTML5 compatibility, it should have loaded in HTML5 mode, but instead, loaded Flash.

Comment: @Brent Sorry I am a little outdated. Haven't used jwPlayer for some time, and as I can see things are different than I am used to.

Comment: One thing to do is a set up like this - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29394/hls-with-mp4-fallback, but instead of making it HLS > MP4, make it RTMP > HLS. This set up totally works.

Comment: @EthanLongTail Updated, thank you. I suspected this was the case.